# Refit - Dynamic AND Static Header

Tags: c#, refit

I am using [Refit](https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit) and would like to set both a dynamic AND a static header. For this one specific call I need to set a content-type of application/json (for others, I do not), but I also need to pass a dynamic bearer token.

I'm getting a 500 error it almost seems like the one header is erasing the other.

Is this valid and will it pass both content-type AND authorization: bearer  ?

```
[Headers("Content-Type: application/json")]
[Post("api/myendpoint")]
Task<bool> GetUser([Body]int id, [Header("Authorization")] string bearerToken);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hello. How did you resolve it. I have the same issue.

Answer (score 12):

Sending dynamic and static headers at the same time is supported by Refit. Here's a working example:

```
public interface IHttpBinApi
{
    [Headers("X-Foo: 123")]
    [Get("/headers")]
    Task<dynamic> GetHeaders([Header("X-Bar")] string bar);
}

// And in the consumer
Console.WriteLine(await api.GetHeaders("bar"));
```

Which writes the following to the console:

```
"{
  "headers": {
    "Connection": "close",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "X-Bar": "bar",
    "X-Foo": "123"
  }
}"
```

If you are finding that the headers are not being set correctly, please [raise an issue on Github](https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit/issues) and ideally provide a small repro project that we can look at.

Answer (score 4):

now "Refit" accept to set multiple headers dynamic:

sample:

```
[Get("/users/{user}")]
Task<User> GetUser(string user, [HeaderCollection] IDictionary<string, string> headers);

var headers = new Dictionary<string, string> {{"Authorization","Bearer tokenGoesHere"}, {"X-Tenant-Id","123"}};
var user = await GetUser("octocat", headers);
```

Comment: Does this over ride default headers?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

Invoking method should be like :

```
var response = await GetUser(1,"Bearer <token>");
```

I found solution here:
https://github.com/reactiveui/refit/issues/693